# How can I preserve an environment variable across su -?

Tags: shell, environment-variables, su

I export `LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"` (via `sendEnv` in ssh_config) when using ssh to remote systems. When I `su - user123` this variable is reset by the login shell. Is there a way to preserve this variable (as well as other `LC_xxx` variables) when executing a login shell as another user on the remote system?

I realize I could export the variable by hand after executing the shell, or an entry in `~/.bashrc` of the target user, however I'd rather try to preserve the original values as sent by `ssh` if possible. Thanks.

**EDIT**: I do need specific parts of the user's environment initialized which is why `su -` is used. I would only want to preserve `LC_xxx`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found that the `su` implementations from `util-linux` and `shadow-utils` (and the one from GNU `coreutils`, though `su` was eventually removed from coreutils)  have an option for preserving the environment:

```
-m, -p, --preserve-environment
           Preserve the current environment, except for:
...
```

Other systems may have `-m` (like on BSDs) or `-p` or both or none. Busybox `su` has both `-m` and `-p`. Toybox `su` (Android) has `-p`.

This way, the target user's shell init files are executed, just as they would be for a login shell, but any `LC_xxx` variables can be tested and not initialized if they contain a valid value already.

**EDIT:** Just a note, I was able to apply this system-wide by adding a script in `/etc/profile.d/ssh_lc_vars.sh` which worked with the exported LC_xxx variables. I also had to do some extra work with the un-initialized environment variables which do not get handled with `su -ml userxxx`. Below is more of an example as I am not able to include the entire script. If someone can improve on it, all the better.

```
...
# clean up client-side variable for junk
lc_sanitize()
{
   arg="$1"
   # first, strip underscores
   clean="${arg//_/}"

   # next, replace spaces with underscores
   clean="${clean// /_}"

   # now, clean out anything that's not alphanumeric, underscore, hypen or dot
   ret="${clean//[^a-zA-Z0-9_\.-]/}"

   # return santized value to caller
   echo "$ret"
}

# LC_MY_LANG comes from an ssh client environment. If empty,
# this isn't a remote ssh user, but set it locally so this user
# can connect elsewhere where this script runs
if [ -z "$LC_MY_LANG" ]; then
   # force an LC_xxx setting for the environment
    LC_MY_LANG="en-US.utf-8"
else
    # otherwise, use the LC_xxxx variable from the ssh environment
    # 2017-01-30 - when using "su --preserve-environment  userxxx --login" be sure to fixup needed variables
    # shorthand: su -ml user111
    export USER=`whoami`
    export LOGNAME=${USER}
    export HOME=$( getent passwd "$USER" | cut -d: -f6 )
    cd ${HOME}

    # sanitize variable which was set client-side and log it
    u_sanitized=$(lc_sanitize "$LC_MY_LANG")
    echo "Notice: LC_MY_LANG sanitized to $u_sanitized from $SSH_CLIENT as user $USER" | logger -p auth.info
fi

# mark variable read-only so user cannot change it then export it
readonly LC_MY_LANG
# set terminal to LC_MY_LANG
export LC_LANG=${LC_MY_LANG}
export LC_MY_LANG
...
```

Answer (score 6):

Skip the `-` parameter of su.

```
   -, -l, --login
       Provide an environment similar to what the user would expect had
       the user logged in directly.
```

Comment: Specifically, use `su username` rather than `su - username`.

Comment: Thanks. I do need the initialized environment provided by the user's login shell however. I would just want to preserve the `LC_xxx` variables.

Comment: so that's what the `-` means! I've been using it blindly.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me, which amounts to invoking an extra shell that will be used to run the command that sets the environment variable.

```
# LC_ALL is set in parent shell
> export LC_ALL=C
> env | grep LC_ALL
LC_ALL=C

# Verify that since we use `su -` the LC_ALL is not preserved
> su - user123 -c '/bin/bash'
user123@026aedc05a97:~$ env | grep LC_ALL
user123@026aedc05a97:~$ exit

# Pass the variable to the extra shell explicitly
> su - user123 -c 'LC_ALL='$LC_ALL' /bin/bash'
# The variable is now set
user123@026aedc05a97:~$ env | grep LC_ALL
LC_ALL=C
user123@026aedc05a97:~$
```