# How to access env variables defined in root from another user?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment-variables, root

I have a env variable `test` defined in the user `root`. This can i access inside user `root` using command:

```
echo $test
```

Now i switch to another user `myuser` using `su - myuser` . Now How to access the `test` variable from `myuser`?

Here is an example of what I am trying to do :
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I preserve an environment variable across su -?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/341258/how-can-i-preserve-an-environment-variable-across-su)

Comment: Nope. unfortunately not

Comment: Welcome to the site. Do you actually mean "environment variables", which `export`ed, or simply shell variables which are only declared/used inside the current shell instance?

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) (as your login shell on Linux) and if you want some environment variable `FOO` to be set for *every user* to string value `bar` you could add in file `/etc/bash.bashrc` (near the end) a few lines like:

```
 # to be added in /etc/bash.bashrc
 export FOO=bar
```

See [§6.2 Bash startup files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) for more.

Of course, you need root permission to edit (once, e.g. with `/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/emacs /etc/bash.bashrc`  in some terminal) that `/etc/bash.bashrc` file.

You could also choose to use other login shells, like [zsh](https://zsh.org/) or [fish](https://fishshell.com/). You need to install their package and use [chsh(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chsh.1.html) to change the `/etc/passwd` entry (see also [passwd(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/passwd.5.html) and file `/etc/shells` documented in [shells(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/shells.5.html)). They have different ways of doing the same.

If the file `/root/.bashrc` is world readable (that might be a cybersecurity risk) you could use the [`eval` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-eval) with [grep(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) or [gawk(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gawk.1.html) on it, using [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html).

Feel free to ask more by email to `basile@starynkevitch.net` (near Paris in France).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a convoluted way:

```bsh
root_test=$( sudo su -l -c 'printf "%s\n" "$test"' )
```

or, assuming root's shell is bash:

```bsh
eval "$(sudo su -l -c 'declare -p test')"
```

Either way, you need to *become* root, in root's login environment, to access the variable's value.

Comment: I tried your both commands but none of them is working for me unfortuantely. I have updated the question with screenshot.

Comment: Do some investigation in the root account: how is that variable getting set? Where is it defined?